# How can I show that every $\Pi_1$ sentence consistent with Robinson Arithmetic is true in the standard model?

Tags: logic, model-theory

> Let $\mathcal{N}=(\mathbb{N}, ...)$ be the standard model of Q (Robinson Arithmetic), and let $\mathcal{N}^{\ast}=(N, ...)$ be an arbitrary model.
>   Let $\varphi$ be a $\Sigma_1$-theorem, and let $\psi$ be a $\Pi_1$-theorem.
>
> Show, that if $\mathcal{N}\models\varphi$, then $\mathcal{N}^{\ast}\models\varphi$.
>   If $\mathcal{N}^{\ast}\models\psi$, then $\mathcal{N}\models\psi$

Hello,

I want to show this statement, and need some help.
My problem is, that our definition of $\Sigma_1$ and $\Pi_1$-theorems is a little bit odd. I hope these are common notations and I would be thankfull if you could give me maybe a link to a definition, which is probably more clear, than our.

Otherwise we might use induction on the complexity of the formula to show this results. 
$\mathcal{N}^{\ast}$ is an arbitrary model. Does that mean that just the carrier-set $N$ can be different of $\mathbb{N}$, or does it also mean $\mathcal{N}^{\ast}$ can contain other functions and relations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: More, than; if, then.

Comment: The proof that $Q$ is $\Sigma_1$-complete is not a trivial proof. Have you seen it? From that you can deduce the fact about $\Pi_1$ statements. And regardless to how you define $\Delta_0$ statements, $\Sigma_1$ are always essentially the same objects: one single existential quantifier over a bounded statement.

Comment: We showed, that if $\varphi$ is a true $\Sigma_1$-theorem, than $Q\vdash\varphi$. In a second task we have to use this statement to proof this result.

Comment: Well, the first part is exactly this. So there's no point in asking about that here. You might as well mention this in your question. I'll write you a hint for the second part.

Comment: I am not sure, if I get you right. we have an other task, which wants us to use the statement above, to proof $Q\vdash\varphi$ for every true $\Sigma_1$-theorem. However, we showed this already in the lecture. Namely: Let $\varphi$ be a true $\Sigma_1$-theorem. Then $Q\vdash\varphi$. Do I understand you right, that the first part of the task above, is exactly this? Therefore we showed $\mathcal{N}\models\varphi\rightarrow\mathcal{N}^\ast\models\varphi$

Comment: What does it even mean that $\varphi$ is a true $\Sigma_1$ sentence? It means that it holds in the standard model.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\lnot\psi$ is a $\Sigma_1$ statement. If $\cal N\not\models\psi$, then it satisfies $\lnot\psi$. Now use the fact about $Q$ and true $\Sigma_1$ sentences to conclude that $\cal N^*$ cannot satisfy $\psi$ either.

Comment: So we use contraposition, right? Let $\psi$ be a $\Pi_1$-theorem. Then is $\neg\psi$ a $\Sigma_1$-theorem. Assume $\mathcal{N}\nvDash\psi$, hence $\mathcal{N}\models\neg\psi$. Therefore $Q\vdash\neg\psi$ and $\mathcal{N}^\ast\models\neg\psi$, which means $\mathcal{N}^\ast\nvDash\psi$

Comment: Yes. That's the point.

Comment: Could you explain, why the first part follows directly from $Q\vdash\varphi$ for a true $\Sigma_1$-theorem? This is not clear to me.

Comment: Well. It's just soundness. If $T$ proves $\varphi$, then $\varphi$ is true in all the models of $T$.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped alot!